# AlertDialog-The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, crash

When I am trying to add `alertDialog.show()` in `ImageViews`(`iView` and `iView2`) , my code crashes and giving

> **The specified child already has a parent. You must call `removeView()` on the child's parent first.**

I dont know why is this happening. Actually I read about this error message and probably giving to using 2 times `alertDialog.show()` Any suggestion?

```
mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relaLayout);
final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            ,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

iView

```
input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    iView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            select = 0;

            alertDialog.setView(input);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                    mLayout.addView(cth[0].setCardView(select, m_Text));
                    iView.setClickable(false);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

iView2

```
iView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            select = 1;
            //input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            alertDialog.setView(input);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                    mLayout.addView(cth[0].setCardView(select, m_Text));
                    iView2.setClickable(false);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

if I comment alertDialog.show() then it's working but I need it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at some of the source, it looks like you're assigning the same view instance (the EditText "input") to the alert dialog.  Each time the `show()` method is called, the dialog is created via `create()`. The view supplied to `setView()` is then added to the dialog layout that is generated. Since that view is added to the layout, it now has a Parent (the dialog layout).  Before you can show the dialog again, you must remove the view from the parent (the AlertDialog), or instantiate a new view.

Simply moving the line (and removing the final modifier, it doesn't need it in this scope) that instantiates the `EditText` to inside the listener solved the issue for me. (I was able to reproduce)

```
iView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        // Create the edit text view.
        EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

        // Set it.
        alertDialog.setView(input);

        // Set it.
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                mLayout.addView(cth[0].setCardView(select, m_Text));
                v.setClickable(false);
            }
        });

        // Set it.
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Show it.
        alertDialog.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code your calling **show()** to the **AlertDialog.Builder** instance. that's why you are getting this issue right.

So you need to create an instance of **AlertDialog** object using **alertDialogBuilder.create()**. this **create()** method returns the **AlertDialog** Object after that you can call **show()**.
So let`s take the code snippet to better understanding as following.
First upol you need to create one of the method called **createDailogObject**.

**createDialogObject()**

```
public/private AlertDialog dialogName; //create global variable
...
createDialogObject();// this line create instance of AlertDialog
...
public void createDialogObject(){
       mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relaLayout);
       EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            alertDialog.setView(input);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                    mLayout.addView(cth[0].setCardView(select, m_Text));
                    iView.setClickable(false);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

           // this following line will creates the AlertDialog instance
           dialogName = .create();
}
...
```

Now you can call the show Method any where!!!.

**iView1**

```
    iView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialogName.show();
        }
    });
```

and Also in...

**iView2**

```
    iView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialogName.show();
        }
    });
```

I will **works 100% sure**.